# Como imprimir variáveis do php dentro de um JS?

Tags: php, javascript

O que eu queria fazer, era colocar dentro de um calendário JS os dados que eu puxo do B.D pelo PHP:
Os eventos nesse formato:

```
events: [{
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, 1),
    backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red 
    borderColor: "#f56954" //red
  }, ],
```

Sendo que eu fiz essa função no PHP só pra pegar todos os eventos do BD e colocar dentro de uma String:

```
  $eventosJS = "";
foreach($eventos as $key => $value) {
  $a = substr($value['data'], -19, 4);
  $m = substr($value['data'], -5, 2);
  $d = substr($value['data'], -2, 2);
  $hrI = substr($value['hora_inicio'], -8, 2);
  $minI = substr($value['hora_inicio'], -5,
    2);
  $hrF = substr($value['hora_fim'], -8, 2);
  $minF = substr($value['hora_fim'], -5, 2);
  $eventosJS = $eventosJS.
  ",".
  "{ title:'Teste ', start: new Date(".$a.
  ",".$m.
  ",".$d.
  ",".$hrI.
  ",".$minI.
  "), end: new Date(".$a.
  ",".$m.
  ",".$d.
  ",".$hrF.
  ",".$minF.
  "), backgroundColor:
  '#f39c12', borderColor: '#f39c12'
}
"; }
```

Mas não sei como colocar o PHP dentro do JS.

Answer (score 0):

Siga essas etapas:

1. Primeiro leia seu JS para uma variavel php, usando a função: `file_get_contents`.

   ```
   $js = file_get_contents('caminho para seu js');
   ```
2. Dentro do seu JS aonde deseja imprimir os valores contidos no array do php vindos de sua Database, crie alguns identificadores:

   ```
   <script> var nome = %nome%; </script>
   ```
3. No seu código php utilize a função `strtr` para substituir os identificadores pelo valor vindo do DB.

   ```
   <?php
       // $values é minha variavel contendo valores do BD.
       $valores     = array('%nome%' => $values['nome']); 
       $code        = strtr($js,$valores);
       /* Indique o cabeçalho como javascript */
       header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
       // Encerre o script enviando o conteúdo do JS
       die($code);
   ?>
   ```
4. Por fim em seu html para vincular o js basta fazer isso :

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="seuarquivo.php"></script>
   ```

Espero que isso resolva seu problema.